# Is there any way to create a deep link from Organic instagram story (not an ad) to a specific content in my mobile app?

Tags: instagram, deep-linking, mobile-application, instagram-story

I want to use an Instagram influencer service with more than 120,000 Followers,
but every time he publishes a story on his profile, the deep link that I Gave him sent users to the app stores and google play and not to the specific product in the app.

It's OK for those who haven't Install the app yet, but what about those who already installed it?
Why do they land on the app store and google play and not on the specific content I wanted?

Of course, that's works OK when I promote an Instagram story ad but is there any way it will work organiclly from a business user with 120,000 Followers? maybe there's a problem with my Deep-link?

thanks!